# hide collapsible Bootstrap 4 navbar on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="myNavbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#Home"></a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon active"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Home">Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I've already tried this code:

```
    $('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

but that's what happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY4if.png)

I found this code on stack overflow too, but I don't know why it isn't working for me.
Can you guys tell me where the problem is?

Comment: your code seems to work fine:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/qgadmtb8/1/ what is the issue!! Did you forget to add any script file

Answer (score 0):

Try  `$('.navbar-collapse').hide();` instead of  `$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');`
Alternatively, if you want it to hide if open, but also to open it if it is already hidden, you can use  `$('.navbar-collapse').toggle();`

Comment: It works! Thanks dude.